# Storyboard not updating when device orientation is changed

Tags: storyboard, xcode8

I use Xcode 8.0

I have a view controller with:

> "Simulated Size" - Freeform

and

> height = 1200.

When I choose different orientations (landscape or portrait) from panel:

[image: Device types]

the preview is not rotating, and storyboard becomes no useful. I can use it for just an orientation (just for portrait).

What could I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, some of the `UIViewController`s were not rotating at all when I change the orientation like you.

What I worked for me was I select the `UIViewController` that doesn't rotate and in the `Attributes inspector` panel, on the `Simulated Metrics` I set the `Size` to `Page Sheet` like this:

[image]

And it works and my `UIViewController`s are regular `UIViewControllers`, not page view controllers.

I don't know if this is a bug.